# Time ordered data structure

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, data-structures

I have a large amount of data that is retrieved from a database.  They are ordered by timestamp (which each item has) and I wish to quickly scroll smoothly through this data as well as being able to retrieve the next/previous record given a specific time.

Is there any data structure that will help me do this?  At the moment I do a kind of binary search through the data to retrieve the next items.

Inserts, deletions and edits are rare (but occasionally necessary) so seek time is the most critical.

Any ideas?

A simple example:

```
public class TimedDataItem
{
    DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}

// Large populated timestamped data set    
IList<TimedDataItem> timedDataItemsList = new Last<TimedDataItem>();

// Get a 'random' time
DateTime myTime = DateTime.Now;

// Find items around that 'random' time
TimedDataItem next = timedDataItemsList.FirstOrDefault(t=>t.Timestamp > myTime);
TimedDataItem previous = timedDataItemsList.LastOrDefault(t=>t.Timestamp < myTime);

// Also foreach over the collection in time order if required
foreach (TimedDataItem item in timedDataItemsList)
    DoStuff(item);

// Inserts, deletions, edits are extremely rare
```

Thanks.

Comment: It seems a "basic" problem - easy to do badly but hard to do right.  I've tried various ordered datasets and they've all required *exact* matches with keys (not next, previous, nearest etc), and LINQ (which will iterate the entire dataset).  Maybe there isn't a nice out the box solution for this?

Comment: Iteration is built into the C# language. Ordering of data in SQL is also built in. It is not clear from your question where you are encountering difficulties. And your comment is not helping. What are you finding so difficult to "do right"?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to post that comment so quickly - apologies :)

Comment: Please post the code you have so we can see exactly what you are talking about.

Comment: OK. Now kindly explain what you mean by "scroll smoothly" - `foreach` should be enough for iteration.

Comment: An example now added to question.  Typically I would have a large populated time ordered dataset (timedDataItemsList) and would receive 'random' times (myTime) which I would use to find the previous/next/nearest items.

Comment: And what exactly is the issue with the approach you have taken?

Comment: LINQ gives O(n).  I'm doing this with 10k+ records, many times.  It seemed like there should be something to speed this up significantly but perhaps not.  In the meantime I'll use a binary search approach which gives O(logn).

Comment: But is this an actual bottleneck for your application?

Comment: Why don't you use some sort of pagination query and only fetch a limited amount of data? If the user scrolls within a certain boundary, fetch the next pagination result. Leave the heavy workload on the server and just get what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Alex - definitely something I haven't thought of, it's an interesting approach but perhaps a very apt one for the problem!

Comment: Is there a reason [BinarySearch()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftfdbfx6.aspx) isn't working for you? Specifically, the bit about how to use a negative complement to find the index of the next highest value.

Comment: My database has indexes. I find it a good place to keep my data and its pretty quick at finding the data I ask for. I've not been inclined to write a database in c#.

Comment: Unfortunately Jodrell, these thousands of records are dynamically generated so not stored in a database.
Tim - thanks, I was using my own but that works perfectly - Doh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Edited answer*

**Preferred solution - SortedSet**

*plus:* sorted collection, allows logic use of elements within a certain range

*minus:* not sure what search algorithm, no previous and next

```
public class TimedDataItem   
{
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
class TimedDataItemComparer : IComparer<TimedDataItem>
{
    public int Compare(TimedDataItem x, TimedDataItem y)
    {
        return x.Timestamp.CompareTo(y.Timestamp);
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SortedSet<TimedDataItem> ss = 
            new SortedSet<TimedDataItem>(new TimedDataItemComparer());

        // example data
        ss.Add(new TimedDataItem() { Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5) });
        TimedDataItem min = new TimedDataItem() { Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3) };
        ss.Add(min);
        ss.Add(new TimedDataItem() { Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) });
        ss.Add(new TimedDataItem() { Timestamp = DateTime.Now });
        ss.Add(new TimedDataItem() { Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1) });
        TimedDataItem max = new TimedDataItem() { Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3) };
        ss.Add(max);
        ss.Add(new TimedDataItem() { Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5) });

        // get elements in range
        SortedSet<TimedDataItem> view = ss.GetViewBetween(min, max);

        foreach (TimedDataItem item in view)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Timestamp);
        }
    }    
}
```

**Solution SortedList**

*plus:* sorted, typeSafe, allows next and prev

*minus:* linear search

```
 SortedList<TimedDataItem, TimedDataItem> sl =
            new SortedList<TimedDataItem, TimedDataItem>(new TimedDataItemComparer());

 TimedDataItem first = new TimedDataItem() { Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5) };
 TimedDataItem second = new TimedDataItem() { Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3) };
 TimedDataItem third = new TimedDataItem() { Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) };
 TimedDataItem fourth = new TimedDataItem() { Timestamp = DateTime.Now };
 TimedDataItem fifth = new TimedDataItem() { Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1) };
 TimedDataItem sixth = new TimedDataItem() { Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3) };
 TimedDataItem seventh = new TimedDataItem() { Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5) };

 sl.Add(first, first);
 sl.Add(second, second);
 sl.Add(third, third);
 sl.Add(fourth, fourth);
 sl.Add(fifth, fifth);
 sl.Add(sixth, sixth);
 sl.Add(seventh, seventh);

 // unfortunatelly according to MSDN: 
 //   This method uses a linear search; therefore, this method is 
 //   an O(n) operation, where n is Count.
 int index = sl.IndexOfKey(third);
 TimedDataItem prev = sl.ElementAt(index - 1).Value;
 TimedDataItem next = sl.ElementAt(index + 1).Value;
```

**Solution ArrayList**

*plus:* allows use of an index, binarySearch (!)

*minus:* what should you do with an index in an unordered collection ...

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
al.Add(first);
al.Add(second);
al.Add(third);
al.Add(fourth);
al.Add(fifth);
al.Add(seventh);
al.Add(seventh);

int index2 = al.BinarySearch(third, new TimedDataItemComparer2());
// al[index2] does not make sense
// as there is no guarantee, that al[index2-1] is the element
// with previous DateTime ...

class TimedDataItemComparer2 : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        if (x is TimedDataItem && y is TimedDataItem)
            return ((TimedDataItem)x).Timestamp.
                       CompareTo(((TimedDataItem)y).Timestamp);
        else
            return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Pilgerstorfer, How exactly would I pull the nearest/next/previous elements from that?  Using binary search as per comments?

Comment: rewrote my answer, choose your preferred solution, hth!